# itertools or functools for find-replace list in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-itertools, functools

I have a set of strings that are sometimes invalid that I'd like to replace with particular better strings.  I've been playing with functools and itertools and would like to try applying these to the problem, but I'm a little stuck.  Here's what I have:

```
s1 = 'how to sing songs'
s2 = 'This is junk'
s3 = "This is gold"
s4 = 'HTML'
s5 = 'html'
s6 = 'i'
mylist = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6]

replacements = [('html','HTML'),('how to sing songs','singing'),('This is junk', ''),('i','')]
```

I'd like a function algorithm that sort of says, for each string in mylist, for each replacement in replacements, string.replace(replacement[0],replacement[1]).

What kind of came to mind was something like...

```
map(lambda x,y: x.replace(y[0],y[1]),mylist,replacements)
map(partial(lambda x,y: x.replace(y[0],y[1]),mylist),replacements)
```

But the first wanted extra arguments, and the second said list object has no attribute replace.  Is there a slick functional way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y[0], y[1]), replacements, s) for s in mylist]
['singing', '', 'This is gold', 'HTML', 'HTML']
```

Equivalent code with `map()` instead of a list comprehension:

```
map(partial(reduce, lambda x, y: x.replace(y[0], y[1]), replacements), mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for.  However, I noticed that if I have in my replace list, something short like 'e', it replaces within words.  How could I modify this to only replace full words?  Am I stuck changing to regexp?

Comment: Yeah you will probably need to do that with regex.

Comment: Cool, I think this worked: `map(partial(reduce, lambda x, y: re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % y[0], y[1],x), replacements), mylist)`

Comment: Yep looks like a good approach, but you may want to do `re.escape(y[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something really fast. In that case you should really be using dictionaries, as lookups are extremely fast.

A working example:

```
mylist = ['how to sing songs', 'This is junk', "This is gold", 'HTML', 'html', 'i']
replacements = {'html':'HTML', 'how to sing songs':'singing', 'This is junk':'', 'i':''}

print [replacements.get(word, word) for word in mylist]  
# ['singing', '', 'This is gold', 'HTML', 'HTML', '']
```

Comment: How is this wrong? It produces the exact same output as FJ's answer. Plus it's much cleaner, and should be much faster. I've edited my answer to show the output it produces.